# my code compiles fine but shows segmentation fault on submission on geeksforgeeks.....i am unable to identify the problem

Tags: c++, c++14

here is my code for the function to check if a set(a2) is subset of another(a1).
in the main function the arrays are declared and then passed to thi isSubset function.
I created a hash array with all elements 0 and incremented it by elements from a1 first then a2
now counted the elements from hash array with value 2.

```
string isSubset(int a1[], int a2[], int n, int m) {
        int max=a1[0];
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(a1[i]>max){
                max=a1[i];
            }
        }
        int hash[max+1]={0};
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            hash[a1[i]]++;
        }
         for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
             hash[a2[i]]++;
         }
         for(int i=0;i<max+1;i++){
             if(hash[i]==2)
             count++;
         }
    
        if(count==m)
        return "Yes";
        else return "No";
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Consider running the code in a debugger so you can see where it crashes and why.

Comment: you should want to get max value from array a1 and a2, but you only get max from array a1. the program may "array out of bounds" when it executes "hash[a2[i]]++;"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential possibilities that you get a SIGSEGV:

1. `a1` is NULL or `a2` is NULL
2. `n` is greater than the size of `a1` so `a1[i]` overflows and reads an invalid address
3. `m` is greater than the size of `a1` so `a1[i]` overflows and reads an invalid address
4. `int hash[max+1]={0};` requires too big buffer size of `hash` one stack which is not available. You could either allocate `hash` in heap or as static in [`.data`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). Or, you might want to employ [`brk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) syscall to increase the available memory of the stack.
5. `a2[i]` is greater than `max` which might lead to an overflow memory access in `hash[a2[i]]`.

I highly recommend you look for how to implement a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). You might interested in [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) [quadratic probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing) [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) and [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining).
If you are tired of rehashing in a static hashtable, you may want to checkout [extendible hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing) and [linear hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) which employs local redistribution instead of global rehashing.

Comment: okk now i understand..... thanks for the help